# Trouble updating Mongodb properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/djDExDmJ39PiCsJTOQ1c?p=info)

I am trying to traverse through a collection, and update each document respectively.

My UserProfile collection consists of multiple JSON objects of userProfiles. As you can see, each profile has a lot of the same information. The only difference is the personal information. (This is just a test case of hard coded objects. The real data will be in an SQL DB managed by a sysadmin).

What I am trying to do is write a function (replaceTopics) that will take in an array of topics and replace each topic that matches in the collection. So if the system admin makes a change to a topic/s, he will send me the topic/s and I will be checking each document in my userProfile collection to see if that document has the matching topic (by matching topicIDs), if so, I need to replace that entire topic with the editedTopic.

I have tried this but with no luck. You can take a look at my function.

Comment: I think it would be better If you left the server side take care of the replacement rather than doing it in the web page. Jackson can be used in this case. Using jackson, create list of UserProfiles objects and the loop through the list. Then using if condition you can perform the actions necessary.

Comment: this is server side. I am using nodejs.